# Eliminate duplicity of serialized json data row in django

Tags: python, django

I am passing a json serialized data to an ajax request on my application after doing some queries on my django app.

How can I eliminate duplicity of my data in the serialized data bellow "data_prod"? I would like to have in the dataset exclusive and unique rows.

Thanks in advance.

Views.py

```
def product_table(request):
   width = request.GET['width']
   length = request.GET['length']
   prod_filter = Product.objects.filter(length=length,width=width).defer('volume')
   data_prod =serializers.serialize('json', prod_filter, fields=('width','length','Name','Model'))
   return JsonResponse({'data_prod':data_prod})
```

Comment: That's not the word you're looking for.

Comment: Hi Ignacio.. what solution would you recommend?

Comment: what about [distinct](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) ?

Comment: When I apply distinct into the queryset considering that I defer one column, it does not generate a unique dataset excluding the defered column. It should be something after the serialization